# three.js ray intersection r58

Tags: three.js, webgl, raycasting

i want   to   detect   intersection    using    ray   in   collada  object,   three.js    r58   but

```
var intersects = target.intersectObjects(ai);
```

not   working  for   me   any   one   solve    this   ?  is   Ray    doesn't    support   intersectObjects()   method   in   r58   or   there   is   any   bug   in the   code?   then    what   is the    alternate   instead    of   Raycasting?

```
    var sphereMaterial = new t.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x333333});
    var sphereGeo = new t.SphereGeometry(2, 6, 6);
    var target;

    function createBullet(obj) {
        if (obj === undefined) {
            obj = cam;
        }
        var sphere = new t.Mesh(sphereGeo, sphereMaterial);
        sphere.position.set(obj.position.x, obj.position.y * 0.8, obj.position.z);

        if (obj instanceof t.Camera) {
            var vector = new t.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 1);
            projector.unprojectVector(vector, obj);
            target=new t.Ray(obj.position, vector.sub(obj.position).normalize());
        sphere.ray= target;
        }
        else {
            var vector = cam.position.clone();
        target=new t.Ray(obj.position, vector.sub( obj.position ).normalize());
sphere.ray= target;     
}



    sphere.owner = obj;

    bullets.push(sphere);
    scene.add(sphere);

    return sphere;
}
```

Comment: Use THREE.Raycaster. See the [Migration Wiki](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) for help upgrading to the current version. Do not rely on old tutorials from the net. Refer to official three.js examples that work with the current version, r.58

Comment: @WestLangley but there is no official example for collada object collision detection

Comment: Only 3 minutes passed before you responded. You need to at least try. Get it working with a simple cube first. Then with a cube that has a child cube. Then with collada. In that order.

Comment: @WestLangley i have tried an everything works fine but now problem is my collada model appears completely black

Comment: That has nothing to do with ray casting. You need to search the posts here and study the three.js examples to see if there is something you are missing. If you are still having problems, then open a new issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
var sphereMaterialc = new t.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0099FF});
var sphereGeoc = new t.SphereGeometry(5, 5, 5);
function createBullet3(obj) {
    var obj = cam;
    var spherec = new t.Mesh(sphereGeoc, sphereMaterialc);
    spherec.position.set(obj.position.x, obj.position.y, obj.position.z);

   
     
        var vector = new t.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 1);
        projector.unprojectVector(vector, obj);

        spherec.ray = new t.Ray(
                obj.position,
                vector.subSelf(obj.position).normalize()
        );
    
    

    
    spherec.id = 'player';
    spherec.owner = 'player';
    spherec.health = 100;
    spherec.lastfive = Date.now();


    bullets.push(spherec);
    scene.add(spherec);
    
    return spherec;

}
```

Comment: Please state the logic behind your code in your question, format it properly and ideally add code comments.